# ppl ,how to use it properly?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, ppl

The following code:

```
#include <ppl.h>
int i;
vector<int> val(10),summ(10,0);
for(i=0;i<10;i++) val[i]=i;

parallel_for(0, 10, [&] (int y){
    vector<int> vett(1000);
    double vall=val[y];

    for(i=0;i<vett.size();i++)
        vett[i]=vall;

    for(i=0;i<vett.size();i++)
        summ[y]+=vett[i];
 });

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
cout<<summ[i]<<endl;
```

Produces random output like: 
0
1000
1468
204
3600
25
5898
7000
7456
1395

I should use "combinable" I guess, but the documentation I found about it is not very good. Do you know how to make this code work correctly? What if vett is a 2d vector?

Since I'd like to learn parallel computing, is it worthy learning this new microsoft library or there are better alternatives?

Comment: What documentation are you using? I've found ["Concurrency Runtime"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx) and ["Parallel Programming with Microsoft Visual C++"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675934.aspx) very useful.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem with your code is the `i` subscript variable. It is being used by multiple parallel tasks **at the same time**. Chaos ensues and is the reason for the wonky results. The simplest fix is to declare the loops in your lambda like this:

```
for(int i=0;i<vett.size();i++)
    vett[i]=vall;

for(int i=0;i<vett.size();i++)
    summ[y]+=vett[i];
```

Note that each loop index is declared in the `for` loop initialization. This is more idiomatic usage and can be used in all your loops, unless you really need the final value of `i` after the loop is finished.

Comment: to clarify, all variables declared in the parallel_for are shared between treads? so by declaring `i` in the `for` initialization you avoid it.

Comment: @MarcoS: The lambda in your code captured `i` in an outer scope _by reference_. This meant multiple tasks shared that single variable. If you declare the variable inside the lambda then each task gets its own instance of `i`. By declaring `i` in the for loop initialization the lifetime is even more restricted to just the loop body.

Comment: Thanks, just declared another int inside the for_loop and results are no longer random. And I know why. Nice

Answer (score 1):

A good rule of thumb for parallel code is to minimize the number of shared variables.

As a consequence, you should never use `[&]` as the lambda capture for `parallel_for` (or `std::thread`).  Capture only the variables that need to be shared.

If you did this, you would have discovered the problem @Blastfurnace pointed out, namely that `i` was shared between all workers.

Comment: I don't know too much about lambda functions so I don't understand what you mean with `[&]`. You mean the index of the 'parallel_for'? I found that as standard example, can that be changed? Seems like lambda functions come first when trying to learn ppl

Comment: @MarcoS: It's not an index.  It's a lambda expression which creates a functor object.  And yes, you should read about lambda expressions before using them with PPL.  For example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx